# Crash on glDrawElements

Tags: opengl

My application is crashing on "glDrawElements" (and glDrawArrays).

**I would like to know, what can be the cause of the crash?**

Currently I've got that:

```
Foreach mesh

     - Bind VBO/VAO

           if( VAO empty )

                - bind VAO(id)
                - bind VBO(id)

                Foreach attribs
                    - glEnableVertexAttribArray
                    - glVertexAttribPointer
                End foreach

                - unbindVAO(0)
                - unbindVBO(0)

                Foreach attribs
                    - glDisableVertexAttribArray
                End foreach

            endif

     - Bind IBO(id)

     - Bind program/shader(id)
        -> send uniforms

     -> glDrawElements

End foreach
```

- My application crash on glDrawElements when I've got many VBO/VAO/IBO
- With different devices, I've got strange artefact when I've got many VAO/VBO/IBO

I think there is something strange with my buffers (like a conflict), what is the correct order for bindings? Where I need to unbind VAO,VBO,IBO,Program, Texture, … ?

EDIT:

It's look like the crash appear when I delete a geometry, his buffers are removed from opengl (because I don't use them anymore). So I think my buffers are always bounded Oo.

**OpenGL Trace:**

```
glBindBuffer(target = GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer = 8)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(index = 2)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 2, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 20, ptr = 0x0)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(index = 0)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 0, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 20, ptr = 0xc)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(index = 4)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 4, size = 2, type = GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, normalized = true, stride = 20, ptr = 0x10)
glBindBuffer(target = GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer = 0)
glBindBuffer(target = GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer = 7)
glUseProgram(program = 0)
glUseProgram(program = 6)
glUniformMatrix4fv(location = 2, count = 1, transpose = false, value = [1.6974937, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.100419, -0.49304545, -0.49301255, 0.0, -1.1902374, -0.87008023, -0.8700222, -9.582167, -2.1815264, 15.627364, 15.64632])
glActiveTexture(texture = GL_TEXTURE0)
glBindTexture(target = GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture = 1)
glUniform1i(location = 8, x = 0)
glDisable(cap = GL_BLEND)
glBlendFunc(sfactor = GL_LINES, dfactor = GL_POINTS)
glEnable(cap = GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glUniformMatrix4fv(location = 7, count = 1, transpose = false, value = [50.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.1, -150.0, 1.0])
glUniform3fv(location = 3, count = 1, v = [0.8235294, 0.8235294, 0.8235294])
glUniform2fv(location = 0, count = 1, v = [0.0, 0.0])
glUniform2fv(location = 1, count = 1, v = [1.0, 1.0])
glDrawElements(mode = GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, count = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indices = 0x0)
```

Comment: What do you upload to your VBO, which arguments do you pass to glVertexAttribPointer and what arguments do you pass to the draw calls? Do (glDrawArrays != NULL) and (glDrawElements != NULL) hold?

Comment: Thanks for your response!

I think all that is ok cause I can draw my scene without problem in most on cases (on devices like nexus 10, some element doesn't appears Oo).

I've saw that crash occure when I remove a geometry/buffers. (I've edited my post to give OpenGL trace)

Comment: Wait, do you actually delete one of the VBOs you're attempting to pull data from? What do you mean you don't need the geometry anymore?

Comment: I've got 2 geometries: The plane (never deleted) and the character geometry (deleted when useless).

In my game, I've got states: Game state (Game with planes and my characters) and Main state (Only planes for interface)

When I am in my game state and I go to the main state (with a click on a button), I remove useless geometry (only character here). The application crash while my character geometry isn't use anymore.

Comment: Well, if you bind a VAO which stores vertex arrays that associate with a non-existing buffer object, i.e. your deleted character, what do you think is going to happen? Just don't try to render from the delete buffer object. Simple as that.

Comment: I've disabled VAO to use only VBO, crash is always here :/

Comment: Please post your code, if possible or paste it somewhere and post a link.

Comment: Oh wow, I don't know how this slipped my attention - `glBlendFunc(sfactor = GL_LINES, dfactor = GL_POINTS)`. Either the software you are using to trace your GL API calls is faulty, or you do not seem to understand what `glBlendFunc (...)` does.

Answer (score 3):

You should not disable vertex attrib arrays *after* unbinding a VAO. In an OpenGL 3 core context, the second you unbind a VAO you no longer have a context for vertex array commands to apply to; you must always have a VAO bound or these commands will be invalid operations.

Moreover, VAOs store vertex array state persistently. The idea is instead of enabling or disabling states every time you draw something, you just bind a VAO that has all of the necessary states already setup.

Here is how you should be thinking about setting up vertex arrays using Vertex Array Objects. Since the VAO stores most of the state, you do not have to do things like disable vertex arrays or unbind VBOs to prevent state leaks. Just change the bound VAO whenever you want to draw a different vertex array.

**Stage 1:** GL Vertex Array / Buffer Object Initialization

```
When Mesh is Constructed:

  - Generate VAO, VBO, IBO
  - Bind     VAO, VBO, IBO

   -> Upload Vertex Data to VBO
   -> Upload Index Array to IBO

  Foreach Attribute <n>
    - Setup  Attrib Pointer (n)
    - Enable Attrib Array   (n)
  End Foreach
```

**Stage 2:** Drawing a Mesh Instance

```
When an Object (instance of Mesh) is Rendered:

  - Bind Mesh's VAO

  - Bind program/shader(id)
    -> send uniforms

  -> glDrawElements
```

Also, unbinding a VAO is really unnecessary if your software is setup correctly (e.g. everything that draws using vertex arrays has its own VAO to manage state). Think of applying textures, you rarely unbind a texture after you draw something. You count on the next batch you draw knowing exactly what texture state(s) it needs; if it needs a different texture (or none at all), then *it* should be the thing to change the texture state. Restoring texture state after every batch is a waste of resources, and so is restoring vertex array state.

On a side note, I was looking at your OpenGL trace and came across something you may not be aware of. You are using `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` indices, which are provided by the API but not necessarily supported by hardware. On a lot of hardware (e.g. any desktop GPU) `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` is the preferred index type (even for very small collections of vertices). It is tempting to assume that using `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` will save space and therefore increase throughput when you have fewer than 256 vertices, but it can actually throw you off the "fast path." If the hardware does not support 8-bit indices, then the driver is inevitably going to have to convert your indices to 16-bit *after* you submit them. In such cases, it increases driver workload and does not save any GPU memory, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

If a buffer is bound to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER when you call glVertexAttribPointer, the pointer is taken to be an offset within the buffer. Otherwise it's taken to be a pointer to system memory. Thus, if there's no buffer bound and you pass an invalid pointer such as zero (expecting a buffer is bound), GL attempts an invalid read and the program crashes.

The same thing for glDrawElements, if a buffer is bound to GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER the pointer argument is taken to be an offset within the buffer.

Here, GL_ARRAY_BUFFER buffers only need to be bound during gl*Pointer() calls and GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER during glDrawElements() calls.

<strike>Enabling a client state</strike> Calling glEnableVertexAttribArray and not supplying a pointer will also cause a crash.

**edit**

I believe a VAO simply records the configuration of vertex attributes arrays, bound buffers and the pointers into those buffers. To use, bind the VAO before setting up everything as though you were going to make a draw call, then unbind. Now when ever you bind that VAO, the state is restored and you can simply make a draw call without a huge bunch of GL calls.

```
bind VAO
for each attrib,
    call glEnableVertexAttribArray //in the next draw call, use the VBO I'm about to set up.
    bind VBO
    call glVertexAttribPointer //use data in bound VBO with size,stride,offset
    unbind VBOconfig
end for
unbind VAO
//not certain but are attrib arrays still enabled after unbinding VAO (maybe disabling is unnecessary)
```

now for a draw call, bind the VAO, draw(), unbind.

Lastly, for glEnableVertexAttribArray and glVertexAttribPointer I don't know but does the index need to be the uniform variable location?

Comment: Passing 0 to glVertexAttribPointer always works, regardless of whether a buffer is bound to ARRAY_BUFFER or not. Furthermore in C++, NULL is often simply defines as 0.

Also, if your talking about client state you neglect that enabled attrib arrays are VAO state, which are mandated for GL 3.2+ core and definitely not client state.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this informations. I've unbounded my VBO after glVertexAttribPointer but problem is already here :(.

It's like that now :
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer->getId() )
for(…)
{
   glEnableVertexAttribArray(…);
   glVertexAttribPointer(…);
}
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );

I'm using OpenGL ES 2, so I haven't got glEnableClientState.

(I have edited my post to give my Opengl trace)

Comment: @thokra Passing 0 as a pointer while no buffer is bound will work, but when a draw call is made and OpenGL tries to read the data at location 0 in system memory the program will crash. My bad I meant enabling an attrib array, thanks (similar consequence though I believe). I'll update the answer.

Comment: @jozxyqk: That again depends on which version and profile your using. With GL3.2+ core, draw calls will generate an INVALID_OPERATION if no VAO is current. Also, VertexAttribPointer needs both a VBO and VAO to be bound or it will generate an INVALID_ERROR as well (at least with the current 4.2 implementation by AMD I have at my hands right now - should be GL3.2+ core though). The spec isn't clear enough on that though. In one place it states exactly what I say above, in others, where it should be mentioned, it doesn't. Time for bug report.

Comment: You can avoid all of this hooplah if you use the Direct State Access extension. Instead of binding a texture, vertex buffer, GLSL program, etc. to change a state (i.e. uniform value, vertex attrib pointer, texture image data) tied to it you can set the state without changing the bound object. Why the extension STILL has not been promoted to core, I don't know - but it's been around for ~5 years and is widely available (GL_EXT_direct_state_access). I should point out that parts of it are core, it was partially re-used for Separate Shader Objects.